# function smoothing with exponent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, smooth-functions

I found this statement in a proof and thought it is clear, thinking of the absolute value function as an example, but I can not give a proof. Can someone give me a hint?

There is a function $f: R^6 \rightarrow R$  ($R$ are the real numbers) and $f\in C^2(R^6\setminus\left\{0\right\},R)$ and continous everywhere. Furthermore $f(0)=0$.

The claim is:

There is $n\in N$ such that $f^n\in C^2(R^6,R)$.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac 1{\log \|x\|}$ for $\|x\|\in (0, \frac 12)$, extended with the proper contiguous quadratic polynomial in $\|x\|$ for $\|x\|\ge\frac 12$, seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: thanks for your hint, how would you define $f$ in zero? It seems that your example might not be continous in zero?

Comment: $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}\log t = -\infty$, so defining $f(0)=0$ preserves continuity.

Comment: I see. And why is it impossible to smooth it with an exponent?

Comment: The derivative of $(\frac 1{\log t})^n$ is $\frac {-n}{t \log^{n+1}t}$ and from $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}t\log t = 0$ it follows that $t \log^{n+1}t=\Bigl(t^{\frac 1{n+1}}(n+1)\log (t^{\frac 1{n+1}})\Bigr)^{n+1}$ goes to $0$ as $t\downarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{\|x\|} \quad \text{if } x\neq 0, \quad f(0)=0 $$

belongs to $C^2(\mathbb{R}^6\setminus \{0\};\mathbb{R})$ but there is no $n\geq 1$ natural such that $f^n$ will be of class $C^2$ in a set including $0$.

Comment: The derivative (the gradient) of $1/\|x\|^2$ is $-2x/\|x\|^4 \in\mathbb{R}^6$. This means that the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the j-th coordinate ($1\leq j\leq 6$) is $\partial_{j}f = -2x_j / \|x\|^4 \in \mathbb{R}$. We say $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is of class $C^2$ in a set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ if it is continuous and both the first and second derivatives exist and are continuous in (every point in) $\Omega$. So in this case $1/\|x\|^2$ is not continuous in $x=0$ neither its derivative, yet they are both of class $C^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^6\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Oh, your example is not continous in zero, so maybe that is the reason why we can not take this as a counter example, So I'm still hoping that someone has an idea for a proof

Comment: Oh the function $f$ is continuous everywhere, i.e. $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^6)$, and moreover $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^6\setminus \{0\})$, right? Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: yes exactly, thanks for your help